# How to query table that has a many-to-many relationship? SequelizeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I know there is SequelizeJS documentation, but I still don't understand how it works.
I have 3 tables `articles-->polit_in_article<--politicians`. and I want to make a query with sequelize that would get all the articles of a requested politician.

This is what I have came up with so far. I really don't know where to put the `req.body` parameters to make this query work.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Article = require('../models').Article;
const Politician = require('../models').Politician;

const Op = Sequelize.Op;

module.exports = {
    getArticle(req, res) {
        return Article
            .findAll({
                include: [{model: Politician}],
                where: {
                    [Op.eq]: [
                        {id: Politician.politicianId},
                    ],
                },
            }).then(result => result)
            .catch(err => err);
    }
};
```